# HSQLDB "CREATE TYPE": "type not found or user lacks privilege"

Tags: sql, hsqldb, user-defined-types, create-table

#### Goal

To use a [`CREATE TYPE`](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#N11580) statement in [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) 2.0.0 to create a user-defined type, and to use that user-defined type in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

#### Example

```
CREATE TYPE MASK_TYPE AS SMALLINT;
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(MY_MASK MASK_TYPE NOT NULL);
```

#### Problem

When I execute the example, I see the following error message:

```
type not found or user lacks privilege: MASK_TYPE
```

#### Questions

1. What errors, if any, exist in the syntax of the example?
2. How might I achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct. You need to execute each statement separately.

Update: This does not work with 2.0.0 but works in the latest 2.2.8

Comment: Thanks for responding, and for your work on HSQLDB!  
Do the following steps conform to your separate-execution advice?  
1. `java -jar hsqldb-2.0.0.jar`  
2. Click "Ok" on "Connect" dialog box.  
3. In the SQL text-entry area, enter `CREATE TYPE MASK_TYPE AS SMALLINT;`.  
4. Click "Execute SQL"; "update count" is 0.  
5. Clear the SQL text-entry area.  
6. Enter `CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(MY_MASK MASK_TYPE NOT NULL);`.  
7. Click "Execute SQL"; see "Database Manager Swing Error" dialog box with `java.sql.SQLException: type not found or user lacks privilege: MASK_TYPE`.